# SwiftUI - Matched Geometry Effect synchronize child views size

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I'm implementing custom menu view with transition appearance from top trailing position. I'm using `matchedGeometryEffect` on views background. The problem is with child views of second view. They appears before animation ends. You can see below:

[image]

How synchronize these button views with animation of parent view?

Below my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var show = false
    @Namespace var namespace
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1.2)) { // Longer duration for demo of issue
                        show.toggle()
                    }
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                        .font(.title3)
                        .background( !show ?
                            Color.clear
                                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "topMenuToggle", in: namespace, properties: .position)
                            : nil
                        )
                }
            }
            .padding()
            Color.clear
                .overlay(
                    show ? MenuView(namespace: namespace) : nil
                    , alignment: .topTrailing
                )
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(Color.black.ignoresSafeArea())
    }
}
struct MenuView: View {
    let namespace: Namespace.ID
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Button(action: {
                
            }) {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Text("Save video")
                        .font(.body)
                    Spacer(minLength: 0)
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.down.circle")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(height: 20)
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, 18)
            .padding(.bottom, 18)
            .padding(.horizontal, 14)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.white.opacity(0.1))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 1)
            Button(action: {
                
            }) {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Text("Report")
                        .font(.body)
                    Spacer(minLength: 0)
                    Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.bubble")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(height: 20)
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, 16)
            .padding(.bottom, 18)
            .padding(.horizontal, 14)
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .frame(width: 250)
        .background(
            Color.white.opacity(0.2)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "topMenuToggle", in: namespace, anchor: .bottomLeading)
        )
        .cornerRadius(12)
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to put content *into* matched view for common animation.

Comment: [SwiftUI Lab](https://swiftui-lab.com) has a great series of posts about `MatchedGeometryEffect` and `AdvancedAnimations` that you will find helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix animation by adding `MatchedGeometryEffect` for each row item and source view. Maybe it's not correct way but it works somehow.
Modified code:

```
Button(action: {
    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.2)) {
        show.toggle()
    }
}) {
    Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
        .background( !show ?
            Color.clear
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "topMenuBg", in: namespace, properties: .position)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "topMenuRow0", in: namespace, properties: .position)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "topMenuRow1", in: namespace, properties: .position)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "topMenuRow2", in: namespace, properties: .position)
            : nil
        )
}
```

**MenuView.swift**

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    Button(action: {}) {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {}
    }
    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "topMenuRow0", in: namespace)
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.white.opacity(0.1))//
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 1)
        // Before frame() the height is broken weirdly
        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "topMenuRow1", in: namespace)
    Button(action: {}) {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {}
    }
    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "topMenuRow2", in: namespace)
}
.frame(width: 250)
.background(
    Color.white.opacity(0.2)
        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "topMenuBg", in: namespace, anchor: .bottomLeading)
)
```

Demo:

[image]